# Toggling between claims exchanges on the same orchestration step Azure B2C

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Is there a way to toggle between claims exchanges on the same orchestration step? So far my experience with b2c is that the user journey only works on a one-way linear path and can't move back through a step.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsProviderSelection" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.providerselection-phoneoremail">
    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpEmail" />
        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="SignUpPhone" />
    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpEmail" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-CollectEmail" />
        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpPhone" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-CollectPhone" />
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a linear one way path through the orchestration steps. You cannot go back to a previous orchestration step.